# Docx file from an XML file of docx

Tags: python, xml, parsing, docx

I was just wondering if there's any way to generate a docx file with a given XML file of a docx.I have been able to perform the reverse process i.e. getting the XML of a docx file as they are zipped together.

Is there any way in python to get this process done.

Comment: It might be worth [edit]ing your question to clarify why you are attempting this. [There are Python modules that can create/update `.docx` format files](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+docx) so it may not be necessary to create copies by hand (via more complex Python scripts) if you can target the specific details you wish to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

A DOCX file is much more complex than one XML files.
It actually contains a series of XML files, organized in several folders.
All the files inside the DOCX are XML files, even those that don't have an
`.xml` extension.

The DOCX contains default themes, document properties, font tables, and so on,
all in XML format.

If you extracted all these XML files, you will have to put them together again
in exactly the same way, or you will lose some functionality.
This is not worth the effort.

For more information, read
[An Informal Introduction to DOCX](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx).